# Securing cPanel and WHM

Tags: security, webserver, tracking, cpanel

Is there a way I can trace users who log in in my cPanel and WHM? I know about cPHulk but it just records users who attack the server. I just want to record every user their IP address that log into cPanel or WHM and also the files they are uploading or downloading.

Answer (score 2):

For the cPanel, following logfiles show information which could be useful:

```
/usr/local/cpanel/logs/error_log
/usr/local/cpanel/logs/access_log
/usr/local/cpanel/logs/login_log
```

Their names are fairly self-descriptive.
[This link](http://www.webmastertools.fm/how-to/View+all+IP'S+of+cPanel+login's,+View) has a lot of information which could be usefull for you.

The FTP login information you could find here:

```
 /var/log/xferlog
```

You can get raw access logs if thats what you are after by logging into your CPanel and selecting the button "Raw Access Logs".